# Multiple API variations or 1 is enough?

Tags: api

So my friend needed to develop new API for creating item, so he developed:

```
POST /new/item
POST /item/new
PUT /new/item
PUT /item/new
```

All of them call the same underlying function and accept same parameters.

I recommended that he uses only 1 instead of 4, but he says that there is no down side and he's giving the option for anyone who wants to integrate with this API to use whatever personal variation they like.

**Question:** Is it really that there is no down side by doing this in the long run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no downside in regards to functionality, but an API with redundant endpoints will probably be

- Harder to maintain. If a change to the endpoint is needed, it may have to be made four times depending on the setup
- Confusing for users of the API. While I imagine it's the intention behind this setup to catch typos in URLs and still allow the API to work, documentation on the endpoints will be bloated and harder to read
- Lacking consistent naming. Ideally, there is a logic behind how endpoints are named, allowing users to infer what an endpoint does by its name and verb (GET, POST etc). Having multiple naming schemes makes it harder to understand the naming.

There is no meaningful upside to making redundant endpoints, and I would recommended to use `POST /item` for creating a new item.